# Verify if a button is disabled in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, button

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-save-m" name="save_m" value="Save my thing" class="form-submit ajax-processed saved-m-processed">
```

I need to verify with Python and Selenium if the button is disabled.
Any ideas?

Comment: check the for the properties or class. I don't see any separate property so it has to be class.check which class makes it disable, seems like `saved-m-processed` class. If it's present element is disabled else not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("edit-save-m")
print element.is_enabled()
```

Prints true or false, based on element visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I’m getting an error:
Failure: NameError (name 'driver' is not defined) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: NameError (name 'driver' is not defined)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I even used from selenium import webdriver and it's strange, cause in PyCharm it looks like it's grayed out and the same error appears...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
className.Property.is_enabled()
```